# How to copy a part of LinkedList into another LinkedList?

Tags: java, collections

I have two LinkedLists. I need to copy a part from the first List (starting with index x and finishing with index y) to the second List. What ways are there to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`List.addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) and [`List.subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> a = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
        System.out.printf("a = %s%n", a);
        List<String> b = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4"));
        System.out.printf("b = %s%n", b);
        int x = 1;
        System.out.printf("x = %d%n", x);
        int y = 2;
        System.out.printf("y = %d%n", y);
        b.addAll(a.subList(x, y + 1));
        System.out.printf("b = %s%n", b);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
a = [A, B, C, D]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x = 1
y = 2
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, B, C]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
One addition to Sash Sinha answer, we can add the sublist at any index using b.addAll(0, a.subList(1, 3)).


    
List<String> a = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
        List<String> b = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4"));
        b.addAll(0, a.subList(1, 3));
        System.out.println(b);

output:

[B, C, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```